# C++ - does string contain a word - with simple loop?

Tags: c++, string, substring

//EDIT

- the code below works only in case that str1 has only 1 beginning letter of str2; how to fix it?
- for ex. if str1 / 2 = overflow / flo it works.
- but if str1 is over**f**low**f**abc (has two "f"s) --> it doesn't work

//
I need to check for a word in a string using simple loop. The idea is:

- find an element in str1 that is equal to 1. element of str2
- if it exists, we set flag = 1, and it remains 1 if following elements are also equal. If they are not, flag is set to 0.

.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str1, str2;
    int flag;
    cout << "Enter a string 1: ";
    getline(cin, str1);
    cout << "Enter a string 2: ";
    getline(cin, str2);

    for(int i = 0; i < str1.size(); i++)
    {
        if (str1[i] == str2[0])   // find element in str1 that is equal to first element of str2
        {
            flag = 1;  // 
            for(int j = i+1; j < i + str2.size(); j++)
                if (str1[j] != str2[j-i])  // checking if following elements are also equal
                {
                    flag = 0; // if any of them is not equal
                    break;
                }

            if (flag==1)    
                cout << "str2 is Substring of str1" ;
            else
                cout << "str2 is NOT Substring" ;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you debug your program? Did you write out its logic with a pencil and some paper? If not, you should go ahead and do that now

Comment: `for(int j = i+1; i < i + str2.size(); i++)` -- That loop looks strange, mixing `i` and `j` up like that, given that this is nested within `for(int i = 0; i < str1.size(); i++)`

Comment: str1.find(str2)? I must be missing something...

Comment: Indeed, why reinvent the wheel...

Comment: `i < i + str2.size();` ok so when do you expect this to become `false`?

Comment: @n.m. - thanks, I fixed the typo, it's  j < i + str2.size() (in tested program no typo; doesn't affect the result though, still doesn't work)

Comment: @EddieIM `for(int j = i+1; j < i + str2.size(); i++)` -- So this is no longer a typo?  What is `i++` doing there in a `j` loop?  This is why you should never type in your code -- copy and paste the code directly from your editor into the StackOverflow edit window.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - you're right, i can't believe I haven't seen such a stupid mistake. Ok, I should definitely get more sleep before I continue ... Fixed and edited, the code now works , but as I see only if str1 has only 1 beginning letter of str2 - for ex. if str1,2 = overflow, flo it works. But if str1 is overflowfabc (has two "f"s) it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
bool isSubStr(const string& parent, const string& child)
{
    // Check each starting position
    for (int i=0; i<(parent.size()-child.size()+1); ++i)
    {
        // Check if the substring starts at this position
        // TODO make this a helper method to avoid the need for a flag
        bool isSubString = true;
        for (int j=0; j<child.size(); ++j)
        {
            if (parent[i + j] != child[j])
            {
                isSubString = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isSubString)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The string class in C++ contains a function named *find*, and in my opinion you should use that.

The documentation can be found [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/).

An excerpt about the *Return value*:

> The position of the first character of the first match.
> If no matches
>   were found, the function returns string::npos.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    string str1, str2;

    cout << "Enter a string 1: ";
    getline(cin, str1);

    cout << "Enter a string 2: ";
    getline(cin, str2);

    size_t found = str1.find(str2);
    if (found != string::npos)
        cout << "str2 is Substring of str1" << endl;
    else
        cout << "str2 is NOT Substring" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It is shorter and easier to understand. So why not going with that ?

Otherwise I believe your code is not correct in more than one aspect; e.g.

- you print out the text depending on the flag variable within the for loop. This does not look right to me.
- the second for loop looks strange to me. I believe you are trying to program something that you believe might be considered sophisticated and well thought. To be honest with you, I suggest that do not try to do that. Do simple and clear.

Following your comment I took the time to try to improve your code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    string str1, str2;
    int flag = 0;

    cout << "Enter a string 1: ";
    getline(cin, str1);

    cout << "Enter a string 2: ";
    getline(cin, str2);

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < str1.size(); i++) {
        if (str1[i] == str2[0]) { // find element in str1 that is equal to first element of str2
            unsigned int j = 0;
            for( ; j < str2.size(); j++) {
                if ( str1[i+j] != str2[j] ) {  // checking if following elements are also equal
                    break;
                }
            }
            if ( j == str2.size() ) { // if j equals the size of substring then all chars seem equal
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if ( flag )
        cout << "str2 is Substring of str1" ;
    else
        cout << "str2 is NOT Substring" ;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks, I'm of course aware that there are functions, but I have to find the solution using loops only, functions and pointers are not allowed

Comment: I added an improved source code to the answer. I hope that helps.